# Got shortlisted for PhD, what to expect?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, philosophy

I applied for a PhD in philosophy at Yale, and I got shortlisted yesterday. I was given the day for the interview on Jan 15. What to expect exactly on the day of the interview, and how to approach it? Thanks! Also, should I respond to the Shortlisting email with Thanks message?

Comment: "what to expect" for _what_, exactly?

Comment: on the day of the interview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know the interviewers, I can only say what sorts of things I'd be interested in. My questioning would mostly be follow ups on what you said (or might have said) in a Statement of Purpose. What do you hope to study, with whom (if you have a sense of that), how does your background support that, and what are your future career plans at the moment. The answers could be pretty specific, or not, but you need to reply sensibly. If you have only a bachelors then I wouldn't expect much that is specific.

If you already have a publication history then I might ask a question about one of your papers. To give a short summary, especially of why it is "interesting".

I might also throw in an off-the-wall question or two as an ice breaker or just to see how you interact to less formal questions. "What do you like to do when you aren't studying? How about those Mets?" (Sorry, NY in-joke).

Yes, thank them for the shortlisting, and confirm the availability for the interview.

Comment: Mets are doing not so good! Thanks